# .forEach within async action creator not returning action when running unit test

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, mocha.js, chai

I am using react/redux to generate a list of panels, each of which displays data on each list item. I set a 5 second interval that calls  refreshAppList(this.props.list) action creator that forEach loops through every item in the list and makes an async call which then dispatches the refreshed list item (using redux-thunk). So basically, every 5 seconds I am refreshing the list of panels with the most up-to-date data. This works great! Unfortunately, now that I am writing unit tests for this particular async action creator I have run into an issue. .forEach does not return anything so when I call it in my unit tests I am getting undefined. Does anyone know how to override this issue or maybe i need to use a different method to refresh the entire list of panels?

Here is the action creator that is looping through the array and making an async call on each array item.

```
export const refreshAppList = list => (dispatch) => {
  list.forEach((version, index) => {
    const url = `apiEndpoint/${version.data.app_id}/${version.data.version}`;
    return axios.get(url)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        data.uniqueId = version.uniqueId;
        data.refreshId = uuidv1();
        dispatch({ type: REFRESH_APP_LIST, payload: { index, data } });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      });
   });
 };
```

Here is the error i am receiving:

```
 1) async actions creates an action with type: REFRESH_APP_LIST:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
  at Context.<anonymous> (tests/asyncActions.js:140:12)
```

Here is where I am calling the action creator within the test (using redux-mock-store):

```
return store.dispatch(refreshAppList(list)).then(() => {
  expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
});
```

I think it is also worth mentioning that I am using axios-mock-adapter to mock the data returned from the async call within the action creator.

One last thing: I have written unit tests for two other async action creators within the same app and both pass. The big difference is that this particular action creator is chaining together multiple async calls using a forEach loop (that is not returning anything to the test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't work because the function that `refreshAppList` returns doesn't return anything. Also, `.forEach` doesn't return anything even though you do return `axios.get.` from inside. You could use `.map` instead and return everything inside `Promise.all`. Something like this

```
export const refreshAppList = list => (dispatch) => {
  return Promise.all(list.map((version, index) => {
    const url = `apiEndpoint/${version.data.app_id}/${version.data.version}`;
    return axios.get(url)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        data.uniqueId = version.uniqueId;
        data.refreshId = uuidv1();
        dispatch({ type: REFRESH_APP_LIST, payload: { index, data } });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
      });
   }));
 };
```

Comment: Awesome! I just realized that I should have said that the *function* that `refreshAppList` returns doesn't return anything (oops). Glad you got it working. :)